# Apache Multi-sites

Tags: apache, apache2

I've created two virtual hosts. tester.ly and tucnak.me

/sites-available/Lab:

```
<VirtualHost tucnak.me:80>
    ServerAdmin kovalevskiy11@gmail.com
    ServerName tucnak.me
    DocumentRoot /home/tucnak/Web/Lab/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/tucnak/Web/Lab/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
            #... here smth skipped.
</VirtualHost>
```

And /sites-available/Tester:

```
<VirtualHost tester.ly:80>
    ServerAdmin kovalevskiy11@gmail.com
    ServerName tester.ly
    DocumentRoot /home/tucnak/Web/Tester/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/tucnak/Web/Tester/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
            # skipped too.
</VirtualHost>
```

And my apache2 output:

```
[Mon Feb 13 20:17:07 2012] [warn] VirtualHost tucnak.me:80 overlaps with VirtualHost tester.ly:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
```

I think that smthing wrong directive cause this problem. So, I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` or `NameVirtualHost *` directive in your configuration.

This mean your starting VirtualHost directives should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
(...)
<VirtualHost *:80>
(...)
```

And not :

```
<VirtualHost tester.ly:80>
(...)
<VirtualHost tucnak.me:80>
(...)
```

The name of the VirtualHost is given by the `ServerName` directive inside the VirtualHost, not by the name used in the `<VirtualHost xxx>`. And this `xxx` should match one of the `NameVirtualHost` declarations in main configuration.